# How does dribbble's color search work?

Tags: colors

How does [dribble's color search](http://dribbble.com/colors) work? It's not like other search by color features. What I can't figure out is how they can have search parameters for color variance and color minimum without storing a row for every individual color in an image (which I suppose is possible).

Comment: The site probably stores the top 10 most prominent colors in the image (with some variance).

Comment: I myself am curious how they do such a good job, when you upload an image they automatically pick the colors out of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colors are usually extracted from the image using a histogram computing the density of the colors. Once, you have the top 5/10/15 colors from the image, performing a search is matching the given color against these extracted colors.

To match a given color against other, various techniques are available such as minimizing the euclidean distance between the two colors. More on such techniques can be read at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization

Similar strategy is discussed in the blog entry http://mattmueller.me/blog/creating-piximilar-image-search-by-color